# Procedure for cc430 rf tuning with chip antenna

Tags: rf, antenna, pcb-antenna, 433mhz, balun

I have designed the 433MHz RF PCB with CC430F5137 with ceramic 50 Ohm chip antenna from Johanson Technology. I have also used Balun from Johanson Technology to match the CC430 and 50Ohm Antenna. I have done the basic testing and it is working fine but the RF range is much shorter than expected. I know it is due to bad antenna tuning. I have kept provision of pi filter footprint in the PCB in case if need for future tuning.

[image]
[image]

Now, what are the steps to do the antenna matching? What equipment I will need to do it? Where should I start from? Is there any tutorial available? Any reference to this procedure would be a great help.

Comment: usually you start with a path loss budget and specs for return loss like >15dB between x-y MHz

Comment: "RF range is much shorter than expected" - so, what did you expect and what did you get. Nobody here is a psychic. Also, in anticipation of you providing the above info, please also provide a link to the data sheets of all relevant parts and a circuit diagram. The picture you have embedded tells me nothing.

Comment: You have to do impedance matching while you cad the PCB, not afterwards.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, Thanks for your reply. But can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @Andyaka, As per TI datasheet they are saying it to be more than 500 meters but my design gets the range of not more than 10 meters. No one is psychic, it is about physics. I just want to know how to tune any source and antenna using pi filter. Do you know the answer? Please share it.

Here is the link to antenna datasheet http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/611/0433AT62A0020-242467.pdf

and Link to Balun Datasheet http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/611/0433BM15A0001-253534.pdf

Comment: @Lundin, I have taken care of the PCB traces and layout guidelines as per datasheets and reference designs. But for final tuning I have kept a provision of Pi filter in between balun and antenna. Do you have procedure to select the components values for Pi filter?

Comment: @user2365252 Enter your values here to match your results then investigate the problems with measurement tools. Most common problem is high receiver threshold due to internal noise or complete lack of awareness of RF connection methods.,. https://www.pasternack.com/t-calculator-friis.aspx  YOu MUST show photos of your layout and hardware , coax, power supplies etc with measurements

Comment: you may be able to tune antenna with a wire loop series diode to small RF cap to DMM to detect peak power in mV and tune antenna

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, thanks a lot. That seems to be the easiest way to tune.